# CanCanCan: How to handle an object that is nil in Ability model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have this controller:

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def create
    @user.save
    respond_with @user
  end

  def update
    @user.update user_params
    respond_with @user
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_with @user
  end

  private

  def user_params
    permitted_keys = [:name,
                      :email,
                      :password,
                      :password_confirmation,
                      :lock_version]

    permitted_keys << :role if can? :edit_role, @user

    params.require(:user).permit(permitted_keys)
  end
end
```

In my ability model:

```rb
    can :edit_role, User do |user|
      user.new_record?
    end
```

The problem is, that when creating a user (`#new` or `#create` action), `@user` is `nil`. So the role can't be set, as it will not be added to the `permitted_keys` on `#create`.

How can this be solved? I could change my controller to:

```rb
permitted_keys << :role if action_name == 'create'
```

But I don't like this, as the `Ability` can be tested much more easily than this.

Another workaround would be this:

```rb
permitted_keys << :role if can? :edit_role, @user || User.new
```

But this feels redundant.

Anybody has a better idea? And by the way - I'm quite surprised that passing `nil` as object to `can?` is allowed and doesn't raise an error. It seems that it doesn't even propagate to the actual configuration in `Ability`, as otherwise `user.new_record?` would raise a `NoMethod` error or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The CanCan docs prescribe defining abilities with blocks a little differently than how you've done it. They suggest using a guard instead of a block for the case you described (when the instance is nil):

```
# don't do this
can :edit_role, User do |user|
  user.new_record? # this won't be called for User.accessible_by(current_ability, :edit_role)
end

# do this
can :edit_role, User if user.new_record?
```

I'd try this. For other information and to see where I got this example, [check these docs](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks#only-for-object-attributes)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It explains why the block is not evaluated when `@user` is `nil` in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem, the `user_params` method is called before the `@user` variable is created; this kind of makes sense, as `user_params` is needed to create the `@user` variable, or at least it is needed to assign the values from the form.

If CanCanCan would assign a new `@user` variable (of type `User`, of course) before assigning the values from the form, the following code would work on `#create`:

```rb
private

def user_params
  permitted_keys = [:name,
                    :email,
                    :password,
                    :password_confirmation]

  permitted_keys << :role     if can? :edit_role,    @user
  permitted_keys << :disabled if can? :disable_user, @user

  params.require(:user).permit permitted_keys
end
```

But as it doesn't do that apparently, the following workaround works for me:

```rb
private

def user_params
  permitted_keys = [:name,
                    :email,
                    :password,
                    :password_confirmation]

  auth_object = @user || User.new
  permitted_keys << :role     if can? :edit_role,    auth_object
  permitted_keys << :disabled if can? :disable_user, auth_object

  params.require(:user).permit permitted_keys
end
```